# What does these red boxes mean within a Task List?

Tags: task-list

[image: Task list Image]

What do these red boxes mean within the Task List? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those are the tabular selection check boxes. This option is located in the view configuration, Tabular view, section.

It allows users to select multiple items for bulk operations in the ribbon, like check in/out, deletion, etc.

Comment: Why are they there?

Comment: To allow you to select multiple items, for things like bulk check in or deletion